# Implement a function calculating the number of positive integers up to and including n divisible by at least one of the primes in a given array

Tags: php, c++, algorithm

**I do not really know c + +, but I need to translate the algorithm in php. Could you help me, especially not clear line std:: transform (...**

task is:
Implement a function calculating the number of positive integers up to and including n divisible by at least one of the primes in a given array. The caller will ensure that this array is sorted and only contains unique primes, so your implementation may take advantage of these assumptions and doesn't need to
check whether they actually hold true.

There is a very efficient algorithm for counting these numbers for any values of n, as long as the list of divisors remains relatively short.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<signed int> gen_products_of_n_divisors(
    const std::vector<signed int>::const_iterator &start,
    const std::vector<signed int>::const_iterator &end,
    signed int n)
{
  if (n == 1)
  {
    return std::vector<signed int>(start, end);
  }
  std::vector<signed int> products;
  for (std::vector<signed int>::const_iterator i = start;
      i != end; ++i)
  {
    std::vector<signed int> sub_products =
        gen_products_of_n_divisors(i + 1, end, n - 1);
    products.resize(products.size() + sub_products.size());
    std::transform(sub_products.begin(), sub_products.end(),
        products.end() - sub_products.size(),
        std::bind1st(std::multiplies<signed int>(), *i));
  }
  return std::vector<signed int>(products);
}

signed int count_divisibles(signed int n,
    const std::vector<signed int> &divisors)
{
  signed int total_count = 0;
  for (signed int i = 1;
      i <= static_cast<signed int>(divisors.size()); ++i)
  {
    std::vector<signed int> products =
        gen_products_of_n_divisors(divisors.begin(),
        divisors.end(), i);
    signed int sign = 2 * (i % 2) - 1;
    for (
        std::vector<signed int>::iterator j =
        products.begin();
        j != products.end(); ++j)
    {
      total_count += sign * n / (*j);
    }
  }
  return total_count;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<signed int> a;
  a.push_back(3);
  a.push_back(5);
  a.push_back(7);
  a.push_back(11);
  a.push_back(13);
  a.push_back(17);
  a.push_back(19);
  std::cout << count_divisibles(1000000, a) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Check a reference for information on std::transform: http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/. Basically, it applies some function (in this case, multiplication with elements in the vector iterated over by i) to every value in a range (in this case, the sub_products vector) and writes the results to another range (in this case, the products vector, starting at index products.size() - sub_products.size()).

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to understand Toolbox's std::transform reference and his or her explanation of how sub-products (products of members of subsets of the set of divisors) are formed, if you are familiar with the [Inclusion–exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  In effect, sub-products that are products of an odd number of numbers add to the total number of divisors, while those that are products of an even number of numbers subtract from it.  This may be more obvious in the following translation to C of the C++ program in question.

In the program, note that `1<<nDiv` is `2^nDiv` (with ^ denoting exponentiation here).  There are `2^k` subsets in the power set of a set of k elements.  Each distinct subset corresponds to a distinct binary ID#. (ID#="identity number").  A set element is a member of a subset if the bit for that element is set in the ID# of the subset.  The program toggles `sign` from -1 to 1 or from 1 to -1 to keep track of even or odd number of bits.

A real program (vs a toy demo like this) should check for overflow when it computes `product` in the innermost loop of `count_divisibles()`.

```
// translation to C of C++ program in question
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int count_divisibles(int n, int *divisors, int nDiv) {
  int total_count = 0;
  int i, it, j, sign, product;
  for (i=1; i < 1<<nDiv; ++i) {
    product = 1;
    sign = -1;
    for (j=0, it=i; j<nDiv; ++j, it=it/2) {
      if (it & 1) {
        product *= divisors[j];
        sign = -sign;
      }
    }
    total_count += sign * n/product;
  }
  return total_count;
}

int main(void) {
  int a[] = {3,5,7,11,13,17};
  int nDiv = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
  int hi, c, k;

  for (hi=1000000; hi; hi/=200) {
    for (k=0; k<nDiv; ++k) {
      c = count_divisibles(hi, a, k);
      printf ("count_divisibles(%d, a, %d) = %6d     a[%d]=%d\n",
              hi, k, c, k, a[k]);
    }
    c = count_divisibles(hi, a, nDiv);
    printf ("count_divisibles(%d, a, %d) = %6d\n",  hi, nDiv, c);
  }
  return 0;
}
```